# WFS Filter in OL3

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I need to filter the features based on attributes

I can not use the WFS GET Request because the data is more in numbers.

If i need to use the XML based Filter do we have any WFS JS Lib which can generate XML for me?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JSONIX (https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) and the precompiled OGC schemas (https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas